My Controller to DropdownList returns with failed to load resource: the serve responded with a status of 500 ()
I'm trying to make cascading dropdowns. The first one works fine but the second is not getting the data from the controller. The DeptID passes through to my GetStores parameter fine, but does not populate the second dropdown.
public ActionResult HistoryView()
{
  var model = new TemplateViewModel();
  model.Depts = _uow.Repository<Dept>().GetAll();

  ViewBag.listCompanies = new SelectList(_uow.Repository<Dept>().GetAll(),"DeptID","Dept_Name");

  return View(model);
}

public JsonResult GetStores( int DeptID)
{
  TemplateViewModel templateViewModel = new TemplateViewModel
  {
    Dept = _uow.Repository<Dept>().Get(x => x.DeptID == DeptID),
    Templates = _uow.Repository<Template>().GetAll().ToList()
  };
  return Json(templateViewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

<div style="background-color:azure; border-color:black; border:solid">
  <br />
  <div>
    <b>Select your Company:</b>
  </div>
  <div>
    @Html.DropDownList("DeptID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listCompanies,String.Empty,  new {style = "width: 200px;"})
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <b>Select Store</b>
    <div>
      @Html.DropDownList("TemplateID", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "--Select Store--", new { style = "width:200px;" } )
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#DeptID").change(function() {
      $("TemplateID").empty();
      $.getJSON('/HistoryLog/getstores', { DeptID: $('#DeptID').val() }, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function () {
          $('#TemplateID').append('<option value=' + this.Value + '>' + this.Text + '</option>');
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>





Have you done any debugging? Please provide details. Start by opening devtools and checking the console for errors. Then check the network tab to see that state and response text of your AJAX request

i get null error for callback

I get a controller return of all Templates for the particular DeptID, am i not searlizing the data correclty?

check server logs for details of the error. Perhaps the response to the request in the browser contains error information, have you checked it?

$("TemplateID").empty();

this line is incorrect because you are not selecting any Tag, you are selecting an element of a dropdown.
so corrected version will be the:
$("#TemplateID").empty();

Then, you are looping on data. Here data is a object and it has property name Templates which you want to populate. So the corrected version will be the:
$.each(data.Templates, function () {

and last one is add quotes around the value in the append method. It will prevent potential issues with special characters in the values:
$('#TemplateID').append('<option value="' + this.Value + '">' + this.Text + '</option>');



Thanks for all the help above, i also needed to create a Helper to searialize the data so i add it and it works!

Please avoid sharing images as your only content.
